# How to use standard ExpandIcon of Table in antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have an antd table in my project
version of antd : 4.25.15
react: "^16.8.6"
It looks like this:

```
<Table
    dataSource={data}
    columns={columnsForRender}
    expandable={expandable}
/>
```

expandable props:

```
const expandable = {
    expandIcon: ({ expanded, onExpand, record }) => {
      if (!record.children) {
        return null;
      }
      return expanded ? (
        <MinusOutlined className='ant-table-row-expand-icon' onClick={e => onExpand(record, e)} />
      ) : (
        <PlusOutlined className='ant-table-row-expand-icon' onClick={e => onExpand(record, e)} />
      );
    },
  };
```

But this button doesn't look quite standard.
I want to use the standard button that is in the Table
example:
1st photo - my button[image]
2nd photo - standard antd button [image]
And i cant use  this expandedRowRender and rowExpandable because this way create a new column

I try to use diffren classes, but a cant use expand and collapsed classes
(maybe i dont know how)